# RHEL json gem installation requires make?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, gem, json

When I try to install json gem (gem install json), at first it fails to do so, because of some  dev package issue. After fixing it, it fails saying that "sh: make: command not found" and "ERROR:  Error installing json: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.". Why is it failing on make? Notice this is not Mac, this is in RHEL 5 (4 or 5, not sure). Why is it not able to do some "build gem native extension"?

Comment: Do you have `make` installed?

Answer (score 0):

To build the extention you need development tools. Install it using this command `yum install Development Tools` "make" program is located in that group as well as other needed dev tools.